# Добавление команд для UserControl wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `UserControl`. Использовать его хочу в двух проектах. Есть такая идея: в `UserControl` заложить весь функционал который может быть доступен, а в приложении просто сделать привязку к интерфейсным элементам. Как мне видится, наверное придётся использовать команды. Подскажите как лучше такое осуществить? Примеры, что я нашел в сети, обычно рассматривают уже имеющиеся команды WPF.

**UPD:**
 Есть `UserControl` на котором расположен `ListBox` для отображения списка автомобилей из БД. В этом `UserControl` я хочу добавить команды добавления/удаления машины. Команды эти выполнят хранимую процедуру из БД.
На главной форме приложения я помещаю кнопки и мой `UserControl`. К кнопкам я хочу привязать команды из `UserControl`. Т.е. в самом приложении, я уже не прописываю выполнение хранимых процедур, это все уже есть в `UserContorol`

Comment: т.е. (применительно к примеру) привязка и работа с бд у вас реализована в контроле, а в коде который использует ваш контрол вы ходите по команде сделать вызов метода реализованного в контроле который выполняет вызов хранимки и т.п.?

Comment: именно. подправил примерчик.

Comment: Вообще, практика обычно обратная - контрол только отображает, а как именно получать и изменять данные - решает вьюмодель. Иначе, ваш контрол оказывается слишком сильно привязан к проекту и переиспользовать не получится его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте попробую показать на примере

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    ...

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(MyCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyUserControl));

    ...
}
```

Тут мы в нашем контроле объявили команду, а то что описали мы ее как `DependencyProperty` даст нам возможность биндить к ней команду из `ViewModel`, например.

Теперь в нужный момент нам надо запустить ее. Пусть этим моментом будет событие загрузки контрола. Дописываем в код выше

```
private void MyUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCommand?.Execute(/*Тут указывается параметр для команды, можно null*/);
}
```

На стороне контрола мы закончили. Теперь свяжем нашу команду с реальным действием. Во `ViewModel` мы опишем команду, которая просто покажет `MessageBox`. В качестве реализации `ICommand` я чаще всего использую `RelayCommand` из `MvvmLight`.

```
public RelayCommand ShowMessageCommand { get; private set; }

private void ShowMessage()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}
```

И в конструкторе `ViewModel` инициализируем

ShowMessageCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowMessage);

Теперь, например в окне, в качестве `DataContext` которого установлен экземпляр нашей `ViewModel` опишем следующее

```
<local:MyUserControl
    ...
    MyCommand={Binding Path=ShowMessageCommand}/>
```

Теперь при вызове строки `MyCommand?.Execute` выполнится функция `ShowMessage`. Для полноты картины не хватает использования параметров. Но там ничего сложно нет. Если все таки сами не разберетесь - спрашивайте.

**UPDATE**

Чтобы у контрола привязать кнопку к `MyCommand`, просто биндим свойство `Button.Command` к `MyCommand`. Таким образом при клике по кнопке будет выполнятся нужная команда. А вот делать так

```
Т.е. в самом приложении, я уже не прописываю выполнение хранимых процедур, это все уже есть в UserContorol
```

Абсолютно неправильно. Контролы не должны брать на себя такой функционал

Comment: Похоже что у меня обратная задача. На стороне `UserControl` мне надо `ShowMessage`, а на стороне приложения только ее вызвать при нажатии кнопки

Comment: Вы писали что > К примеру: Есть UserControl на котором расположен DataGrid привязанная к базе и получающая от туда сведения. Для добавления данных я вызываю хранимую процедуру. Так вот как этот вызов поместить в команду? Или может быть есть другие пути. Как вы реализовывали подобные решения? < Дак вот, вызов процедуры не должен происходить в контроле, это задача как раз таки `ViewModel`

Comment: немного подправил пример, того что мне нужно

Comment: А если не использовать MvvmLight

Comment: В `WPF` есть свои реализации `ICommand`. `RoutedUICommand`, например. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468791/wpf-icommand-mvvm-implementation - тут сами реализовали

Comment: не пойму, почему не работает. Можете глянуть одним глазком [тестовый проект](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am_HYXrscbF78iOkYSDZ1tEibZpD)

Comment: При работе с `WPF` очень полезно заглядывать в окно `Output` студии. В вашем проекте туда выводится сообщение `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ShowMessageCommand' property not found on 'object' ''Well'`. Вы для родительского грида кнопки в качестве контекста данных установили `ElementName=WellsList,Path=SelectedItem`, т.е. `SelectedWell`, а в нем нет команды `ShowMessageCommand`

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу @Donil (с которым я полностью согласен):

Смотрите. UI не должно заниматься никакой «деятельностью», тем более обращением к базе данных. Правильный дизайн должен быть таким:

1. У вас в VM есть `ObservableCollection<CarVM>` и команды `AddCar` и `RemoveCar`.
2. Коллекция должна поддерживать список машин в актуальном состоянии, команды `AddCar` и `RemoveCar` должны запускать асинхронно обновление базы моделью и затем, вероятно, обновлять список машин. Общение с базой — вопрос модельного уровня, а вот задача поддерживать список в правильном состоянии — вопрос для VM.
3. Контрол должен прибиндить коллекцию как `ItemsSource` в свой `ListBox`, и выставить кнопки (или что-то аналогичное), у которых к свойству `Command` прибиндить команды из VM.

Всё.